# sending arguments to block View in the tpl file

Tags: drupal

I have a block View that is displayed like so in my page.tpl.php file:

```
<?php if (!empty($subslider)): ?>
        <div id="subslider">
          <?php print $subslider; ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

In the View Ui I set this default php argument:

```
$url = explode('/',$_GET['q']);
$slideshow = node_load($url[1]);

if($slideshow->field_slide_ref[0]['nid']){
return $slideshow->field_slide_ref[0]['nid'];
}else{
return '';
}
```

It grabs the reference id set in the page node.

Now, my problem is that im using page.tpl.php for other types of content that aren't necessarily nodes with a reference id in the url. I still want to pass an argument to the block View though. How do I do this in my template file?

Thanks

EDIT:

subslider is a block region. Im using Views Slideshow to make a slideshow.

I dont think I can use views_get_view_result because that just retrieves an array.. I need the actual slideshow.

Comment: You should note how you are generating $subslider in your page.tpl.php.  We don't know if it's a region, or if you're populating it from template.php. views_embed_view() may be what you're looking for to programmatically get the output of a view with arguments, but I'm not clear everything to really be able to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment, I mentioned [views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6), which is different than views_get_view().

```
$slideshow = views_embed_view('my_slideshow_view', 'block_1', arg(1));
```

Also note, you don't need to explode $_GET['q'].  You should be able to access URL arguments with: arg(0), arg(1), arg(2), etc....

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this for a while. If you use `view_embed_view()` then you should read http://drupal.org/node/823056 at it explains what you have to do to make it work for a views_slideshow.

**Another solution** is to use JQuery. First you add the views_slideshow block to your content region. Then you create a div container on the page `<div id="my-rotator">&nbsp;</div>` where you want it to appear (i.e. edit the node)

Then in your page.tpl.php add the following script but you'll need to replace `block-views-my_image_rotator-block_2` with the name of your views block - find it by using Firebug:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(  function(){

      var oNewContainer = $("div#my-rotator");
      var oRotator = $("div#block-views-my_image_rotator-block_2");

      oNewContainer.append(oRotator);

    });
  </script>
```

PS. You can control on what page the views-slideshow appears by configuring the block